# How do I make sure a whole tab is visible after scrolling?

Tags: javascript, html, css

After clicking the scroll button, the buttons inside tabs div are supposed to be scrolled to the left for a certain amount of pixels, but I sometimes end up with some buttons that are visible only just part of them.

So my question is how do I make sure that the start button inside the visible area of the tabs div is always visible 100%?

I have tried calculating with clientWidth, offsetWidth and many other variables and do not know how to proceed.

FYI, I do not know how many buttons will there be in advance and buttons have a different length.

JavaScript:

```
function moveLeft(){

    var items = document.getElementsByClassName('item');
    var wrapper = document.getElementById('tabs')
    var clientWidth = wrapper.clientWidth;
    var scrollWidth = wrapper.scrollWidth;

    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        items[i].style.left = '-'+clientWidth.toString()+'px'
    }
}
```

CSS:

```
    #wrapper {
        width: 300px;
        white-space: nowrap;
    }

    button {
        display: inline-block;
    }

    #tabs {
        width: 300px;
        display: inline-block;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    .item {
        position: relative;
        left: 0;
        transition: left 1s;
        margin-right: 20px;
    }
```

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="tabs">
        <button class="item">Tab1</button>
        <button class="item">Tab2Tab2Tab2</button>
        <button class="item">Tab3Tab3Tab3Tab3Tab3Tab3</button>
        <button class="item">Tab4</button>
        <button class="item">Tab5Tab5Tab5Tab5</button>
        <button class="item">Tab6</button>
        <button class="item">Tab7</button>
        <button class="item">Tab8</button>
        <button class="item">Tab9</button>
        <button class="item">Tab10</button>
        <button class="item">Tab11</button>
        <button class="item">Tab12</button>
        <button class="item">Tab13</button>
        <button class="item">Tab14</button>
        <button class="item">Tab15</button>
    </div>
    <button onclick="moveLeft()">></button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend not to go the certain pixel size way but move it by a length of let's say 2 divs. This way you would have to have a counter to see how many times was the event fired to keep track of with which elements' width should you calculate.

So the code would look something like this.

```
var widthToMove = items[counter*2].clientWidth + items[counter*2+1].clientWidth + 40 //40 for the margin in between
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            items[i].style.left = items[i].offsetLeft - widthToMove + 'px';
        }
```

I would not use the clientWidth for this as when you move the elements to the left the width increases. Which would mean that it would move differently everytime it was fired.